# CSS -active Menu with triangle selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

[This is what I want to emulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSCXP.png)
I am looking to emulate this type of menu, where the selector moves from one item to another with an animation and the page contents slide in to the viewport.

For example, if I click the 'Work' option when I am in the 'Hire' section, I want the content of the 'Work' page to slide-in to the view with the triangle selector going to the 'Work' section simultaneously. I tried a few options using Jquery, but failed miserably. Would be awesome if someone could help me out here! TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#tabs27 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1IZB.gif') repeat-x top left;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvitica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#tabs27 ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: auto;
}
#tabs27 ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
}
#tabs27 ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #FECCC3;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 22px 0 22px;
  height: 28px;
}
#tabs27 ul li a:hover,
#tabs27 ul li a.current {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVLDh.gif') no-repeat top center;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs27">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='http://#' title='menu1' class='current'><span>menu1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='http://' title='menu2'><span>menu2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='http://' title='menu3'><span>menu3</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a full page slider library [fullPage-jQuery](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/) or [SuperSlides](http://nicinabox.com/superslides). you will need to make some changes (obviously) in css to get the desired triangle effect in menu but this will get you started.